# Getting page slug

Tags: loop, slug

So if I search 'How to get current page slug', there are bunch of results that suggest to use following snippet.

```
global $post;
$post_slug = $post->post_name;
echo $post_slug;
```

But issue is, if I use it on pages where there is default loop, it will return slug of very first post from the default loop. What am I missing here? This answer seems globally accepted, am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Well, on Pages in the default loop it should only contain one post, the Page. Maybe you have a query somewhere messing things up, try using `wp_reset_postdata()` before your `global $post` ( and/or `$post->post_name`)

Comment: I've had this same problem.  @Howdy_McGee is right, you likely have a different query running in a function or somewhere else that you didn't use wp_resent_postdata()

Comment: I tried using `wp_reset_data();` before calling 'global $post' but it still behaves same. Please correct me, should it work on taxonomy template? or I am doing it wrong by trying to get slug on Taxonomy page. I know that I can use get_queried_object() and term from it. But I have complex scenario so maybe I will have to use combination of both.

Comment: Taxonomy templates show groups of posts. There are no "Pages" attached to a taxonomy or even a term. Are you trying to get the term or are you trying to get a post attached to the term?

Comment: I will try to rephrase my problem, I have some common links on multiple pages. Few of it are links to categories and few of it are for posts. I want to highlight those if you are viewing that category or that post. But problem is, If I use any methods to get permalink/slug of current post/taxonomy being viewed, it returns values for first post from loop while viewing taxonomy instead of that taxonomy itself. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you are inside the loop, you don't need to access global $post, you already have $post variable accessible in your local scope, and this variable holds the data from current loop iteration.
2. If you are outside the loop, then you need to access global $post first, and it will hold whatever data it was left with (the first post in the loop usually).

As I understand, you're trying to output the slug of the current post in your custom loop (not main). In this case, just use `$post->post_name`;